# Can you set a variable with the same name directly after each other?

Tags: coldfusion

I need to set a variable in Coldfusion with the same name directly after each other. I need to do this and there is no other alternative. Obviously if I could set two variables with different names I would.

The second variable needs to overwrite the first one.
I have done this and it works. My question is if in fact there is any reason why it should **not** be done.

For example:

```
<cfset variable_one = "a">
<cfset variable_one = "b">
<cfoutput>#variable_one#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: A better question is why you would ever want to do this? Why would you set a variable and then immediately overwrite it?

Comment: I said in my comment that I don't have a choice. There is obviously a lot going on between the two variables and it is complicated. I don't have a choice.

Comment: You answered your own question. Yes, there's no technical restriction why this would not work.

Comment: I'd sat your question was phrased inaccurately. You said you "...need to set a variable in Coldfusion with the same name *directly* after each other", but now "...there is... a lot going on between the two variables..." which contradicts your original question.  Based on the new information, there is nothing inherently wrong with changing the value of a variable. In fact, that's why its called a "variable" and not a "constant".

Comment: What on earth does the fact that the variables are directly after each other or not directly after each other have to do with the question? 

"My question is if in fact there is any reason why it should not be done." 

That was was the question. 

Why must every answer on SO always come with a slew of useless information, totally irrelevant to the question? Instead of questioning WHY a question is asked, when the question is clearly obvious, don't people just answer the question. I mean, if the question irritates you so much, why bother answering in the first place?

Comment: People on the internet have a love affair going on with pedantry. To answer your question @MarthinusStrydom - you can do what you're describing. As I'm sure you are aware, giving the same variable a 2nd value will overwrite the first value, so you should do whatever you have to do with value #1 before assigning value #2. Beyond that, no restrictions really. It's just not best practice, is all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are basically asking if there is any reason to not do something that you are compelled to do.

Comment: @MarthinusStrydom - It is not an irritating question, but the initial wording, combined with an intro level question, could make some folks wonder if you are new to the language and misunderstanding something about variables. Hence the follow-ups. To answer your question, yes you can overwrite variables as many times as you want. Doing so *immediately* does not really make sense, but is technically valid. In most cases, it makes no difference. It *might* pose potential threading issues when there are shared scopes involved (application, server, etcetera), but that is really case by case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why ***it should not be done*** is that the developer that will work with your code after you, could spend quite some of ***his time*** trying to understand why you did it. (that developer could be you, a few months/years in the future)